# Cannot create or delete db on Plesk server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, plesk

Today I came to the realization that I cannot add or delete any of the databases that belong to any of my clients on my Plesk server.

I *had* been receiving this error:

> Error: Unable to remove some of the selected databases. The user
>   specified as a definer ('root'@'localhost') does not exist

So I found and ran this fix:

```
# plesk db
# CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Now when trying to add or remove a database I receive a *new* error:

> Error: Connection to the database server failed: View 'mysql.user'
>   references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or
>   definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them

(I'm not sure if it is related or not, but I updated MariaDB a few days ago. I'm pretty sure that I created a new database after doing so though).

*‪CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 (Core)‬ | 
Plesk Onyx‬ | 
Version 17.8.11 Update #80‬ | 
mysql   10.4.11-1.el7.centos‬ | 
10.4.11-MariaDB MariaDB Server*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems root@lo...got removed when you upgraded MariaDB few days ago.

**Choice 1:**
It would have removed root@127... also and you would have used both root user references to your databases, connected dbs, **views**, etc. **Views** mainly as the error points to that also. So try this too.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

**Choice 2:**
After re-creating root, try

```
flush privileges
```

If not Ok, you shall restart mysql and try.

```
systemctl restart mariadb.service
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

When I try to run flush privileges it returns a ->. I have to Ctrl-C to get out. I'm a complete noob BTW!

Comment: My bad, I'm not used to the syntax and I forgot to put a semicolon after FLUSH PRIVILEGES. Once I figured that out your tip worked. THANK YOU!

Comment: Fine. Also, **try not to use root@** and create individual users for group of databases with which you can organize securely.